# Symfony 3.1.3 not loading assets

Tags: php, assets, symfony, assetic

I installed Symfony 3.1.3 and yesterday I lost whole day to figure out why symfony's not loading css files, I'm using Assetic bundle, I followed steps from documentation, I also watched videos on youtube, dumped assets, cleared cache but still nothing..
So, I have this code in base twig:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
  {% stylesheets 'bundles/app/css/*' filter='cssrewrite' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
  {% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock %}
```

I also tried to specify concrete file path but 404 not found.

any ideas?

Comment: If you use assetic the path to file shoul be: @AppBundle/Resources/css/*

Comment: does not not work

Comment: What do you see on the server, under `./web/bundles/app` ?

Comment: And what you do you in the generated HTML, where it should be including the stylesheet?

Comment: {% block stylesheets %}
            {% stylesheets '@AppBundle/Resources/css/*' %}
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
            {% endstylesheets %}
        {% endblock %}

Comment: anso tried {% block stylesheets %}
            {% stylesheets 'bundles/app/css/*' %}
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
            {% endstylesheets %}
        {% endblock %}

Comment: @Arkadi What you mean by "does not work"? There a lot of "not work" signs. Where is your css files located? What path to css files is generated in your browser?

Comment: @malcolm I mean that css links are not generated and when I'm triing to reffer to a file for example: http://localsite/bundles/api/css/bootstrap.min.css it retrievs 404 not found. my css files are located in web/bundles/api/css

Comment: No wonder why it's not working. If you do `assets:install` (for ex. composer do it for you) then your css files are removed probably (did you check if they stil exist?) Why you want to use assetic if you files are already in web folder?

Comment: I just get started with symfony and I read somewhere that it was recommended, I don't know if there is any better way to avoid assetic I will switch to it

Comment: At least I figured out that css file not loading when I use spacial address for accessing site, I wote in hosts file: 127.0.0.1 models and also configured apache httpd.conf file, so when I type models/ in my browser it reffers to localhost/models/web/app_dev.php..
from localhost/models/web/app_dev.php {{ asset('bundles/app/cssfile.css') }} loads successfully, but not from models/ how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, after updating the cache, you will want to install the assets too:

In Symfony 3:
`php bin/console assets:install web --symlink`

In Symfony 2:
`php app/console assets:install web --symlink`

Comment: did you mean bin/console ?

Comment: @Arkadi. I did. I cut and pasted from a Symfony 2 installation. `app/console` was in Symfony 2. They moved it to `bin/console` for Symfony 3. I'll update the answer to reflect this.

Comment: "Did not work" as in there was an error message? Or "Did not work" as in everything seemed fine, but you still can't load assets?

Comment: There is no error message just nothing happening when I refresh page